# unable to understand why adding zero in end after adding digits

Tags: c++

http://www.spoj.com/problems/JULKA/help me solve this question please .explain why we are adding zero in end after addition of bits.as commented in code below

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <string.h>

     #define MAX 111

     char klaudia[MAX], natalia[MAX], total[MAX], diff[MAX];

      void calc()
      {
          int len1 = strlen(total);
          int len2 = strlen(diff);
          int a, b, c, i, j, k, f;
          char temp[MAX];

          for(i=len1-1, j=len2-1, k=c=0; i>=0 || j>=0 || c; i--, j--, k++)
          {
               a = i>=0? total[i]-'0' : 0;
               b = j>=0? diff[j]-'0' : 0;
               temp[k] = (a+b+c)%10 + '0';
               c = (a+b+c)/10;
         }
        temp[k] = 0;//explain

        strcpy(klaudia,"0");
         //explain below for loop what is actually being done in this loop//
         for(i=k-1, j=a=f=0; i>=0; i--)
         {
             b = (a*10 + temp[i]-'0') / 2;
             a = (a*10 + temp[i]-'0') % 2;
            if(b) f = 1;
            if(f) klaudia[j++] = b+'0';
        }
         if(!j) j++;
         klaudia[j] = 0;

         for(i=len1-1, j=len2-1, k=c=0; i>=0; i--, j--, k++)
         {
             a = total[i]-'0';
             b = j>=0? diff[j]-'0' : 0;
            if(a < b+c)
           {
                 temp[k] = (10+a-b-c) + '0';
                 c = 1;
           }
            else
           {
              temp[k] = a-b-c + '0';
              c = 0;
           }
      }
      temp[k] = 0;

    strcpy(natalia,"0");
    for(i=k-1, j=a=f=0; i>=0; i--)
    {
            b = (a*10 + temp[i]-'0') / 2;
            a = (a*10 + temp[i]-'0') % 2;
            if(b) f = 1;
            if(f) natalia[j++] = b+'0';
    }
    if(!j) j++;
    natalia[j] = 0;
 }

    int main()
    {
         while(scanf("%s %s", total, diff)==2)
          {
             calc();
             printf("%s\n%s\n", klaudia, natalia);
         }
          return 0;
    }
```

why are we adding zeo in array temp after we have added all the digits

Comment: Because C-strings need to be terminated with a `'\0'` character, to be handled correctly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ then do i need to add back slash \ also in order to terminate the string??

Comment: No, either plain `0`, or `'\0'` (note the `'`!), it's effectively the same.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So? They are adding `'0'` to `ints` and `chars`.

Comment: @juanchopanza OP was asking for this particular statement: `temp[k] = 0;//explain`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah, OK, I thought they meant all the `.. + '0'` part.

Comment: @juanchopanza can you please explain the for loop also

Comment: @TT can you can explain the for loop please

Comment: @codingisfun **One** question / **one** answer at a time!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so you mean i paste the whole code again to ask the thing i forgot to ask???

Comment: @codingisfun I mean, you have to post the _relevant_ code for **another question** you want to ask about it. Also consider accepting the answer for this one, if it solved your problem stated here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks finally got the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are not computing with number but with character string. In C, character string are terminated by a `Nul` character whose code is zero.